# Search and replace text that containing formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, replace, find

I have formula certain cells in the excel column B with the date. When it comes to VBA, the code doesn't work with the line I bold.

The formula in excel in cell B2 is ="OPENING BALANCE AS AT 01.01."&Sheet1!B1&""

The below VBA is work provided I hardcoded cell B2. Appreciate if someone can help on this.

---

```
Sub test3()
Dim FileToOpen As Variant
Dim OpenBook As Workbook
Dim Filename As String
Dim Filename1 As String
Dim Filename2 As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for your FIle & IMport Range", FIleFilter:="Excel Files,*xlsm*")

If FileToOpen <> False Then
    Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
    
Dim src As Range: Dim trg As Range: Dim cell As Range
Dim wbT: Dim rgS As Range: Dim rgT As Range: Dim addr As String

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tax-Timing_P&L")
    Set wbT = .Cells
    Set src = .Range("B1", .Range("B99999").End(xlUp))
End With

With OpenBook.Worksheets("Tax-Timing_P&L")
    Set trg = .Range("B1", .Range("B99999").End(xlUp))
End With

With src
    Filename = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Value
     **.Replace "Opening balance as at 01.01." & Filename & "", True, xlWhole, , False, , False, False**
    Set rgS = .SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlLogical)
    **.Replace True, "Opening balance as at 01.01." & Filename & "", xlWhole, , False, , False, False**
End With

With trg
    .Replace "Tax Timing Summary", True, xlWhole, , False, , False, False
    Set rgT = .SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlLogical)
    .Replace True, "Tax Timing Summary", xlWhole, , False, , False, False
End With

If Application.CountA(rgT) = Application.CountA(rgS) Then
    For Each cell In rgS: addr = addr & cell.Address & ",": Next
    i = 0
    For Each cell In rgT
        cell.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 2).Copy
            wbT.Range(Split(addr, ",")(i)).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial xlValues
        i = i + 1
    Next
End If
```

Comment: I think, even if you can pass this `.Replace "Opening balance as at 01.01." & Filename & "", True, xlWhole, , False, , False, False` line... I think you still won't be able to get the rgS, because I don't think the result from that replace line will be a range of cells with TRUE value, while the rgS is to get all cell which is no blank and which has TRUE value. Also, what is the value in cell B1 ? In other words, what is the value of Filename variable ? Is it something like : `Sheet1!B123&""` ?

Comment: Cells in Column B are text, just the particular cell that i would like to replace is embedded with formula. Not sure how to fix this. :(

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean with `a cell value is a text embedded with formula` ? If cell B2 value like this `="OPENING BALANCE AS AT 01.01."&Sheet1!B1&""` ---> isn't this a formula ? not a text/string value ? Also, what does it mean `&""` at the end of it ?

Comment: cell in Sheet1 B1 is 2023, hence it appears in B2 as "OPENING BALANCE AS AT 01.01.2023".

Comment: What I mean: what does it mean to have `&""` at the end of `="OPENING BALANCE AS AT 01.01."&Sheet1!B1&""` ? what happen if you remove the `&""` ? so inside cell B2 `="OPENING BALANCE AS AT 01.01."&Sheet1!B1`. Also, are there the exact same value ---> `="OPENING BALANCE AS AT 01.01."&Sheet1!B1&""` inside column B besides in cell B2 ?

Comment: Yes, if click into cell B2, it is ="OPENING BALANCE AS AT 01.01."&Sheet1!B1&"" i tried to remove &"" but still cannot locate the cell